# Gson Array of Strings to JsonArray

Tags: java, json, gson

I'm using Gson and am trying to add a bunch of string values into a `JsonArray` like this:

```
JsonArray jArray = new JsonArray();
jArray.add("value1");
```

The problem is that the add method only takes a `JsonElement`.

I've tried to cast a String into a `JsonElement` but that didn't work.

How do I do it using Gson?

Answer (score 73, accepted):

You can create a primitive that will contain the String value and add it to the array:

```
JsonArray jArray = new JsonArray();
JsonPrimitive element = new JsonPrimitive("value1");
jArray.add(element);
```

Comment: Why is this so **ludicrously** counterintuitive?

Comment: And why do the docs tell us there is a JsonArray.add(String)?!?

Answer (score 4):

Seems like you should make a `new JsonPrimitive("value1")` and add that.
See [The javadoc](http://goo.gl/Yje4f)

Answer (score 4):

For newer versions of Gson library , now we can add `Strings` too. It has also extended support for adding `Boolean`, `Character`, `Number` etc. (see more [here](https://static.javadoc.io/com.google.code.gson/gson/2.6.2/com/google/gson/JsonArray.html#add-java.lang.String-))

Using this works for me now:

```
JsonArray msisdnsArray = new JsonArray();
for (String msisdn : msisdns) {
    msisdnsArray.add(msisdn);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I was hoping for something like this myself:

```
JsonObject jo = new JsonObject();
jo.addProperty("strings", new String[] { "value1", "value2" });
```

But unfortunately that isn't supported by GSON so I created this helper:

```
public static void Add(JsonObject jo, String property, String[] values) {
    JsonArray array = new JsonArray();
    for (String value : values) {
        array.add(new JsonPrimitive(value));
    }
    jo.add(property, array);
}
```

And then use it like so:

```
JsonObject jo = new JsonObject();
Add(jo, "strings", new String[] { "value1", "value2" });
```

Voila!